# Meteor.com meta issue: can't change Meteor account email address

Tags: meteor

I don't know if official Meteor.com folks watch this tag closely, but there ought to be the ability to change our account email address. I don't see a way to do that now.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this on [forums](https://forums.meteor.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to do with a simple mongo operation.

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set: {'emails.0.address': 'newemail@mydomain.com'}})
```

Here is a demo: http://meteorpad.com/pad/CzjyYKydhv4n34D4D/Leaderboard

PS:

`Meteor.userId()` and `'newemail@mydomain.com'` should be changed to the user and the new email and obviously you'll have ot take care of the allow/deny rules for user/collection to ensure security.

Comment: This is a development related tag for Meteor Framework. For Meteor.com support, using https://forums.meteor.com might be more effective.